# View outside it's parent's bounds not visible when animated in

Tags: android

I have two TextViews inside a toolbar. When a user clicked on one item from the first fragment, I want to animate the first TextView out of the toolbar and the second TextView in.

[Here](https://youtu.be/tuKZipJK_rQ) is what I have.

The remaining part of the second TextView is still not visible after the animation.

I am animating the two TextViews using TranslateAnimation.

What I am doing wrong?

Here is the layout:

```
...

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    ... >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        ...>

        <RelativeLayout ...
            android:clipChildren="false" >

            <TextView ... />
            <TextView ... />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Here's my code for animating the TextView:

```
TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, -56);
anim.setFillAfter(true);
textView2.startAnimation(anim);
```

Comment: Please provide your code

Comment: @SteveLuck I already added the code.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the contructor TranslateAnimation(context, attrs) which attributeSet is a xml translate. For example:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true">

    <translate
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromYDelta="0%p"
        android:toYDelta="-100%p" />

</set>
```